# bloquear upload maior que 2mb com PHP

Tags: php

Galera como eu bloqueio um upload maior que 2mb?

Estou capturando o arquivo assim:

```
$imagem = $_FILES["imagem"];
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Cada chave/ficheiro de $_FILES pussui uma chave `size`, que por default vem medida em bytes. Podemos converter assim

para 2mb:

```
if($_FILES['imagem']['size'] > 2097152) {
    echo 'não é permitido';
}
```

Para 2gb:

```
if($_FILES['imagem']['size'] > 2147483648) {
    echo 'não é permitido';
}
```

Nota que para 2gb é um grande ficheiro, tem de ter as configurações certas no servidor, php.ini:

```
post_max_size = 2048M
upload_max_filesize = 2048M
```